# YQL Unexpected Token Illegal error

Tags: javascript, yql

I am trying to scrape the rss feed of vimeo using YQL, here is [link to my code on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/udagis/1/edit)

But I keep on getting the folowing error in the console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL 
query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%20SELECT%20*%20FROM%20rss%20WHERE%20ur…channels%2Fstaffpicks%2Fvideos%2Frss%22&format=json&callback=top_stories:1
```

I am following the [yql documentation given here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-tutorials.html#), and have double checked everything.
[Here is the link to a sample code given in the yql documentation](http://jsbin.com/idoyid/1/edit), which works fine.

Need help figuring out what is the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space after `q=`. Try removing the %20. Try the same query [here](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20rss%20WHERE%20url=%22http://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/videos/rss%22&format=json&callback=top_stories) with the space removed.

Comment: Tried it that way here, http://jsbin.com/udagis/6/edit , still the same error in console.

Comment: So the space was a definite issue. I am checking your link on firebug on firefox. I get the following error:SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]   

...eator":"Kauri Multimedia","description":"<p><a href=\"http://vimeo.com/56804197\...

yql?q=...=cbfunc (line 1, col 60)